# How do I use smoke pellets in the Search and Destroy campaign?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

To earn the Smoke Detector medal in the Search and Destroy campaign, I have to

> Use the Smoke Pellet to create a smoke cloud and take down a henchman as he panics in the smoke.

I've hit <kbd>←</kbd> twice on the D-pad to select the smoke pellet, but pressing <kbd>L1</kbd> throws the batarang.  Holding down <kbd>L1</kbd> doesn't seem to work either.  **How do I use the smoke pellet?**  Is it a future gadget upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toss a smoke pellet in the following ways:

- Tapping triangle while under fire
- Choosing it, aiming with L1 and tossing with R1
- Tapping R2 while aiming with L1

You can always review the controls by going into the WayneTech menu and choosing Smoke Pellet under Gadgets

Comment: I played the challenge some more tonight and discovered you can only use the smoke pellet *once*.  Also, to get the medal, you have to do a silent takedown in the smoke.